# When I combine two reducers in the store, my maps with lists stop working in the project and show an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reduce, redux-toolkit

**My store and reducers**
When I combine two reducers in the store, my maps with lists stop working in the project and show an error.
**Error - Uncaught TypeError: tovars.map is not a function**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 
import ordersReducer from "../components/content/tovars/tovarsSlice";
import loginReducer from "../components/content/login/loginSlice";

const stringMiddleware = () => (next) => (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'string') {
        return next({
            type: action
        })
    }
    return next(action)
};

const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
            tovars: ordersReducer,
            login:  loginReducer
        },
        middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(stringMiddleware),
        devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production', 
    })
export default store;
```

I tried to do const tovars = useSelector((state) => state.tovarsList);, but it doesn't work

> But when I leave only one reducer in the store, everything works.

**My component**
After connecting the second reducer, an error occurs on all map functions in the project.

```
const Tovars = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const tovars = useSelector(tovarsList);
    const showBasket = useSelector((state) => state.showBasket);
    const displayedTovars = useSelector((state) => state.displayedTovars)

    const { loadingTovar, errorLoading } = useLoadingStatus();
    const listRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTovars());
},[dispatch])

useEffect(() => {
      listRef.current?.scrollIntoView()
  }, [tovars,displayedTovars]);

const renderTovars = useMemo(() =>{

      const list = tovars.map((item,id) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
                <div className="content_card">
                    <p className="title_card">{item.title}</p>
                    <p className="category_card">{item.category}</p>
                    <NavLink to="/InfoCard"  className="nav-link">
                        <img src={item.image} 
                             alt="card"
                             onClick={() => dispatch(selectCard(item,item.id))} />
                    </NavLink>
                    <div className="price_rating_card">
                         <p className="price_card">Price: {item.price} $</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="del_card">X</div>
                    <button className="card_buy"
                            onClick={() => dispatch(addTovar(item))
                            }                     
                    >Buy</button>
                </div>
                
            </li>
        )).slice(0, displayedTovars)

    return <ul className="list">{list}
               <div ref={listRef}></div>
           </ul>
},[dispatch, tovars, displayedTovars]) 

const nextClickTovars = useCallback(() => {
      dispatch(nextDisplayedTovars(displayedTovars + 6))
},[dispatch, displayedTovars])

const backClickTovars = useCallback(() => {
      if(displayedTovars <= 6){
        return false;
      }
      dispatch(backDisplayedTovars(displayedTovars - 6)) 
},[dispatch, displayedTovars])

    return(<div className="content">
            <div className="filter">
                <Filter />
                <ShowDiscounts />
            </div>
            <div className="spinner_tovars">
                  {loadingTovar}
                  {errorLoading}
            </div>
             <div className="content_tovars_pagination" >
                <Pagination nextTovars={nextClickTovars}
                            backTovars={backClickTovars}
                 />
                  {renderTovars}
                <Pagination nextTovars={nextClickTovars}
                            backTovars={backClickTovars}
                 />
             </div> 
                  {showBasket && <BasketModal />}
           </div>)
}
export default Tovars;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the reducer functions are passed to the `reducer` property of the store configuration, the state is `tovars`, e.g. `state.tovars`.

```js
reducer: {
  tovars: ordersReducer,
  login: loginReducer
},
```

In the component ensure you are selecting the correct state.

Example:

```js
const tovars = useSelector(state => state.tovars);
```

Or ensure that the `tovarsList` selector function is correctly accessing and selecting the correct state.

Example:

```js
const tovarsList = state => state.tovars;
```

```js
const tovars = useSelector(tovarsList);
```

Ensure that all dispatched action that update the `state.tovars` state maintains the correct state invariant. Based on the usage it appears that `state.tovars` is an array. Make sure the local `tovars` variable of the selected state is an array value such that `tovars.map` is a function that is callable when rendering. If this isn't possible to maintain the state invariant then at least refactor the selector function to guarantee a returned array if `state.tovars` is falsey.

Example:

```js
const tovarsList = state => state.tovars || [];
```

```js
const tovars = useSelector(tovarsList);
```